# clojure iterate equivalent in scala?

Tags: scala, clojure

Recursion is cool, but sort of low level when you are surrounding by higher order library functions. I am trying to avoid writing a recursive function for a process that depends on the last value generated.

I would usually use [`iterate`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) function in Clojure over a "zipped" list of last value and current parameter. Is there an equivalent function in Scala's collection API?

Here is an attempt at an abstract example in some crazy pseudo code:

Say you have

- An input list: `Seq(1,2,3)`
- Some action you perform to the last value generated and the next item in the list:

  `lastValue ^ 2 + nextInt(i)`

and you want to accumulate all the values generated.

I am trying avoid writing something similar to:

```
def f(ls:Seq[Int]):Seq[Float] = {

  def g(pos:Int, lastGen:Float):Seq[Float] = { 
    val v = gen(lastGen, ls(pos))
    if( end(v) )
      Seq(v)
    else
      Seq(v) ++ g(pos+1, v)
  }

  f(0, 1)
}
```

I have seen something similar in defining a lazy stream version of Fibonacci in Haskell, so hypothetically I could use a lazy stream that referred to itself, but that is harder to wrap my brain around than Clojure's iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the higher order function you want is [`scanLeft`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), which is like a fold that remembers its intermediate steps. For example, say you have the following:

```
val ls = Seq(1, 2, 3)
def gen(lastValue: Double, n: Int) = math.pow(lastValue, 2) + n
```

Then you can combine them like this with `scanLeft`:

```
scala> ls.scanLeft(1.0)(gen)
res0: Seq[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 39.0)
```

This is more or less equivalent to Apocalisp's formulation with `foldLeft`, except that `scanLeft` takes care of holding on to the intermediate values for you.

Comment: exactly. i was trying to decipher why it was called scan left when i was reading about this method previously. still a little shaky on why its named so

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you're looking for? It's basically the same thing as [`iterate`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate) in Clojure:

```
List.iterate(1, 5) { _ + 1 }
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I think the definition of `iterate` for `List` comes from [`GenTraversableFactory`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/GenTraversableFactory.html#iterate%5BA%5D%28A,Int%29%28%28A%29%20%E2%87%92%20A%29%3aCC%5BA%5D).

The only downside is that the second argument `len` is the number of arguments you want, so it doesn't return an infinite sequence like `iterate` does in Clojure.

***Update:***

Just learned something new! The [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream%24) object has an `iterate` method too, and this lets you create infinite lazy streams:

```
(Stream.iterate(1) { _ * 2 } take 5).toList
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 8, 16)
```

Comment: sorry i should have searched beyond google, straight in scala api. i'll try to ask less obvious q's in future (:

Comment: Don't worry. It took me a while to find it—and I already knew it existed. The Scala API is kind of confusing in my opinion, especially with all the implicit conversions. You can't actually find "iterate" on the List's API page, and just googling for "iterate" returns a bunch of results on `Iterator` instead. I actually found it by looking for the `tabulate` method, which I figured would be in the same place.

Comment: I recommend using `Iterator` instead of `Stream` because it doesn't cache the calculated values (which is not needed here).

Answer (score 3):

The code you showed is basically equivalent to something like:

```
ls.foldLeft(List(1.0))((a, b) => gen(a.head, b) :: a).reverse
```